# how to say Relationship chemistry

Tags: translation

I know there is a word to describe "relationship chemistry" in Chinese. I think it's a 2-character word. Sort of like Extrasensory perception (ESP).

How would you say this?

Comment: "relationship chemistry" and "extrasensory perception (ESP)" are two different concepts. Did you mean to seek a term for "mutually perceived relationship chemistry"? if so, I would suggest, 會心( unspoken/unexpressed understanding between minds/ connected in mind) be a valid choice.

Comment: 我们两个有（心灵）感应？ ？？

Answer (score 1):

靈犀?

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000065618

心有**靈犀**一點通

or, in the past, 紅線 + 月下老人

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000087005

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000164586

info added.

one character? then it must be 緣, which could be translated to fate, destiny, or serendipity.

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000011822

the fourth explanation:

```
人與人或事物之間遇合的機會
```

"有緣" is the simplest usage

Comment: 靈犀=  mutual understanding; (of mind) spiritually connected  , 紅線= (of a couple) joined / linked by fate

Comment: Or maybe it's one word? These words aren't coming to mind. It's sort of like 我们两个有[word]

Comment: 靈犀 also means " spiritual inspiration" in modern Chinese

Comment: @growler, maybe "有緣", see the answer :)

Comment: @Growler In English relationship chemistry can be improved, while 灵犀/缘分 are predestined and immutable. Maybe 默契 (tacit understanding) is the word you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/44349/

> **投契** /tou2 qi4 /  get along well; see eye to eye; be **congenial**

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/congenial

> **congenial** (kənˈdʒiːnjəl; -nɪəl)
>   adj ... 2. having a similar disposition, tastes, etc; compatible; sympathetic

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/9018/

> **投機** /tou2 ji1 /[2] congenial; **agreeable; amiable**

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/13057/

> **合拍** /hap6 paak3/   ( Cantonese jyutping ) :**in harmony**; ...

Quote from OP:"*Sort of like Extrasensory perception (ESP)*".

Compare to the classical term **靈犀** (spiritually connected), **會心**( unspoken/unexpressed understanding between minds/ connected in mind) is a more modern term.

**Update:**

> Or maybe it's one word? These words aren't coming to mind. It's sort of like 我们两个有[word]

If it is one word,  the answer is simple, it is either **緣** or **feel**

我们两个有[**緣**]

我们两个有[**feel**]

"有緣" = fated union

"有 feel" mixed Chinese and English, but it is quite a common term in Hong Kong

Answer (score -1):

As you said 2-character word I guess you want 默契.